# Grouping Anagrams

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions

Please be über brutal, and treat this as a technical interview question.

I was wondering how this function that I wrote looks like.  It groups together words that have the same alphabets (i.e anagrams).

Time Complexity: \$O(n^2)\$

Space Complexity: \$O(n)\$

```
private static List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(ArrayList<String> words){
          List<List<String>> groupedAnagrams = new ArrayList<>();
          AbstractMap<String, String> sortedWords = new HashMap<>();
          Set<Set<String>> sameAnagramsSet = new HashSet<>();
          for(String word : words){
              char[] wordToSort = word.toCharArray();
              Arrays.sort(wordToSort);
              sortedWords.put(word, new String(wordToSort));
          }
          for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : sortedWords.entrySet() ){
              Set<String> sameAnagrams = new HashSet<>();
              sameAnagrams.add(entry.getKey());
              for(Map.Entry<String, String> toCompare : sortedWords.entrySet()){
                  if(entry.getValue().equals(toCompare.getValue())){
                      sameAnagrams.add(toCompare.getKey());
                  }
              }
              if(sameAnagrams.size() > 0){
                  sameAnagramsSet.add(sameAnagrams);
              }
          }
          for(Set<String> set : sameAnagramsSet){
              groupedAnagrams.add(new ArrayList<>(set));
          }
          return groupedAnagrams;
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the right abstractions in method parameters and local variables, for example instead of:

> ```
> private static List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(ArrayList<String> words){
>       AbstractMap<String, String> sortedWords = new HashMap<>();
> ```

would have been better as:

```
private static List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(List<String> words){
      Map<String, String> sortedWords = new HashMap<>();
```

that is:

- `ArrayList` method parameter type changed to `List`. Or actually, if the ordering of words is not important, then `Collection` would be even better.
- `AbstractMap` local variable type changed to simply `Map`.

---

Instead of:

> ```
> if(sameAnagrams.size() > 0){
> ```

this would be better:

```
if (!sameAnagrams.isEmpty()) {
```

---

If I'm reading it right, it seems the algorithm could have been simplified to a single `for` loop:

```
private List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, List<String>> groupedAnagramsMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    for (String word : words) {
        char[] wordToSort = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(wordToSort);
        String key = new String(wordToSort);
        List<String> anagrams = groupedAnagramsMap.get(key);
        if (anagrams == null) {
            anagrams = new ArrayList<String>();
            groupedAnagramsMap.put(key, anagrams);
        }
        anagrams.add(word);
    }
    return new ArrayList<List<String>>(groupedAnagramsMap.values());
}
```

This implementation produces equivalent list of list, if you don't mind the ordering of items.

If you could forgive changing the method signature to return `Collection` instead of list, then the last `new ArrayList` could be omitted, for cleaner and better result:

```
private Collection<List<String>> groupAnagrams(List<String> words) {
    // ... same as above
    return groupedAnagramsMap.values();
}
```

Comment: I thought its always better to declare the apparent type of an object with its superclass/interface, in this it is abstractMap

Comment: `AbstractMap` implements `Map`, therefore `Map` is a better generalization of your purpose. It's better to design in terms of interfaces instead of implementations. The important thing is that `HashMap` implements `Map`. In contrast, the fact that `HashMap` extends `AbstractMap` is an implementation detail, and not at all important in your design.

Comment: Another key point in using `Map` is that, anything that properly implements `Map` would do the job, it need not extend `AbstractMap`. If your code depended on anything contained in `AbstractMap` and not in `Map` then using `AbstractMap` would have made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution by janos.

One minor thing to add is to avoid adding duplicates to the list

```
if (!anagrams.contains(word) {
     anagrams.add(word);
 }
```